# How to use Drupal Queue module in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Can someone tell me, how to use the Drupal Queue module ( http://drupal.org/project/drupal_queue ) in Drupal 6? I have searched for some examples and tutorials, but could not find anything that clearly shows it's usage. I have been using Drupal 6 for quite sometime but have not started using Drupal 7 yet, and not familiar with the new Queue API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a back port of the new [Drupal 7 Queue API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.queue.inc/group/queue/7)

Examples and explanation can be found in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think, I will go and study about the Queue API and also check the module's code.